# trouble with clone in fuction [Ruby]

Tags: ruby

How propertly cloning Array in function

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
    
def ustaw1( do_zmiennej, ze_zmiennej )
  do_zmiennej = ze_zmiennej.clone
end
    
def ustaw2( do_zmiennej, ze_zmiennej )
  do_zmiennej = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(ze_zmiennej))
end
    
a = (1..4).to_a
b = a.clone; b[1] = 99
puts "a == #{a} b == #{b}"
c = Array.new #c = []; a.each_with_index{|e,i| c[i] = e+10 }

ustaw1(c, a)
puts "ustaw1 (c,a) c == #{c}"
ustaw2(c, b)
puts "ustaw2 (c,b) c == #{c}"
          #ale
c = a.clone #lub a.dup
puts "clone c == #{c}"
c = b.clone
puts "clone c == #{c}"
```

normal clone works, but Marshal , clone etc not working in def function (or in object functions)

Comment: I no write not working but working without def and not working with def . Question is how writing function. You are trouble with undestanding what I wrote. Meybe my question is not good writing in english. Feel free to improve text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
def working(a,b)
 b.each_with_index{|e,i| a[i] = e }
end
```

this code is working ok

Answer (score 2):

```
def set_array(a,b)
 a.replace(b.clone)
end
```

Simple and fast. Better creating a normal object

Answer (score 0):

Ruby passes arguments like arrays by pointer, not by value. So when you do `ustaw2(c, b)`, you're not passing the actual variables `c` and `b`; you're passing pointers to the arrays. The variables in the function are new variables which happen to point to the same data. Ruby has no equivalent to "call-by-reference" in C# or C++, so you need to return values from functions to get output

Comment: Question is how writing function for to do this

Comment: "so you need to return values from functions to get output" - generally, yes. However, in case of array, you can just nuke its content via the pointer. [`ary.replace(another_ary)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-replace) and this will be reflected in the caller scope.